# how to do asp.net routing in secure pages?

Tags: asp.net, ssl, routes

is it possible to do asp.net routing in secure pages? we are not following MVC pattern  but need to implement url rewriting in one of the pages. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. Setting up URL rewriting for secure pages will be the same for non secure pages.

Comment: its not url rewriting..asp.net routing.

Comment: Yes. Routing is also possible since it's just redirecting to a page.